# Special Expression not allowed - Regular Expression in PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am trying match my String to not allow the case: for example **150x150** from the image name below:

> test-string-150x150.png

I am using the following pattern to match this String:

```regex
/^([^0-9x0-9]+)\..+/
```

It works fine, Except in such a case:

> teststring.com-150x150.jpg

What i need to get - the mask must disallow only dimensions in the **end of string**, here is some examples:

> test-string-150x150.png > must disallow
>
> any-string.png > allow
>
> 200x200-test.png > allow
>
> 1x1.png-100x100.jpg > disallow

Comment: I think you meant `^(?!.*150x150).+$` https://regex101.com/r/stzGJF/1 Using a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) like `[^0-9x0-9]+` has a different meaning. It matches 1+ times any of the listed.

Comment: @Thefourthbird 150x150 its for example. I meant any numbers. it can be 300x300, 5x5 etc...

Comment: Then you could change it to `^(?!.*\d+x\d+).+$`

Comment: @Thefourthbird Alright it's work! But what if this mask (150x150) must be in the end of string between letters and .jpg (extension). For example i need pass this string: 100x100.jpg-anyletters.jpg and disallow this string: anyletters-100x100.jpg

Comment: Have you tried @Thefourthbird's answer? it works for all these cases.

Comment: @Toto look i need pass first lane https://regex101.com/r/stzGJF/3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a negative lookahead to assert that the string does not contain the sizes followed by a dot and 1+ word characters till the end of the string.

```
^(?!.*\d+x\d+\.\w+$).+$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?!` Negative lookahead, assert what is on the right is not

  - `.*` Match 0+ occurrences of any char except a newline
  - `\d+x\d+` Match the sizes format, where \d+ means 1 or more digits
  - `\.\w+$` Match a dot, 1+ word characters and assert the end of the string `$`
- `)` Close lookahead
- `.+` Match 1+ occurrences of any char except a newline
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Oc5MQH/1)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you're trying to find image names that do *not* include the image dimensions. If so, try this:

```
/^(?![\w-\.]+(\d+x\d+))[\w-\.]+\.\w+$/gm
```

For details about this code, please see [regexr.com/4tmd1](http://regexr.com/4tmd1). This site is a great place to play around with regexes to make sure you're getting the results you expect.

Be aware that the exact syntax of the regular expression depends on the regex engine used by whatever program you're running.

Comment: Yes, Looks good! But what if i need this dimension only in the end of string for example: 100x100-test.jpg - must allow)

Comment: @programmer403, try this:
`^(?![\w-\.]+(\d+x\d+\.\w+$))[\w-\.]+\.\w+$`